# Why does GRASS r.buffer not buffer the raster pixels perfectly?

Tags: qgis, raster, grass-gis, buffer

I have used the GRASS tool `r.buffer` to buffer some raster pixels:

[image: first]

but the execution is not perfect:

[image: second]

The yellow grid cells are the buffered raster, but one can still see the raster grid cells from the old layer.

Why doesn't the tool buffer the outer raster grid cells perfectly but rather the inner grid cells?
How can I make sure the whole area is buffered with 100 meters - also the periphery of the area?

Comment: 1: Your raster is in EPSG:4326, thus units are in degrees. Buffering does not make sense. Re-project to a projected CRS first. 2: Can you provide your data for testing?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "buffer perfectly". The `r.buffer` module adds values to NULL cells in the input raster based on the distance from cells with values in the input. The `distance` parameter value determines how many pixels will get a distance value in the output. Can you explain more clearly what you want to do?  Also, as Babel pointed out, your raster is in EPSG:4326, and you have requested 100 m buffer. If the cell size is greater than (approx) 100 meters, than you will not get any pixels in the buffer in some directions.